# Why using template literal to display the values inside a redux store gives object?

Tags: redux

I'm following this video: https://youtu.be/YAevAj6X6XU?t=499.  At 8:19 min, there is a console.log statement:

```
console.log('Update state: ', store.getState())
```

I tried the program but I tried to use template literal:

```
console.log(`Update state: ${store.getState()}`)
```

What was printed is: `Update state: [object Object]`

Why I cannot display the content of a redux store using template literal ?  Or I have done something wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template literal would try to convert anything you put in there into a string - and since the contents of a Redux store are usually an object, you will see the same thing as if you were calling `anyJavaScriptObject.toString()` - `[object Object]`.

Comment: oh.. so is there another way to evaluate and display store.getState() ?  I remember using {vars} would evaluate the contents vars inside but it does not seem to work.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, why are you not using the shown `console.log('Update state: ', store.getState())` in the first place? That's a perfectly fine way of doing that.

Comment: I'm now using that.  I just wonder how I could write a template literal for it, eg I want to create a standalone template literal for reuse but it contains variables such as store.getState().

Comment: A normal template literal gives you a string - you'd need to convert your object to a string, e.g. with JSON.stringify. But there is really no sensible reason to do that. Why are you so bent on using a string literal?

Comment: I coming from a learning perspective.  I don't have to use that in this situation.  May be in the future, I don't know.  So I just wanted to know.  I got your idea.  That's very helpful for me.  Thanks very much.